# cannot figure out how to produce some tikz pictures next to each other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subcaption

Ideally I would like to have the `tikzpicture`s be in one line centered horizontally with its caption each preserving its node size and line strength and vertically aligned to a common bottom line. I am quite stuck however - therefore all help is much appreciated as I simply have no time to work through the `subcaption` manual (if a better alternative is out there, a hint is appreciated too) and definitely not `pgf` manual documentation right now - though the `pgf` manual is on my todo list for sure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,shapes,positioning,petri,topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_1$}
                \label{fig:20140812k1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_2$}
                \label{fig:20140806k2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (1,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (3,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_3$}
                \label{fig:20140812k3}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (1,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (5,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (3,2) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (3,4) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_4$}
                \label{fig:20140812k4}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (4,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (1,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (5,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v5) at (3,4) [circle, draw] {};

                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_5$}
                \label{fig:20140812k5}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (4,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (1,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (5,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v5) at (2,5) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v6) at (4,5) [circle, draw] {};

                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v5) -- (v6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_6$}
                \label{fig:20140812k6}
        \end{subfigure}%
         \caption{Vollständige Graphen $K_1$ bi $K_6$}\label{fig:completeGraphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure that I entirely I understand your description of what you want. What do you mean by preserve node size and line strength, for example? At any rate, put `\centering` after `begin{subfigure}` and before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and that should solve the horizontal-alignment issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to center each tikzpicture inside each subfigure. You achieve that with `\centering` just to the left of the `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Also, giving every subfigure the same width (`0.16\textwidth`) is a good deal.

To have every subfigure in the same line, you should probably play with document margin, because with six figures you are very probably exceeding `\textwidth`. I think that will not be possible, because to get them in the same line I set 10[mm] to the left and right margins. Perhaps a better option is to have three `subfigure`s per line, what can be achieved with a simple `\\` between the third and fourth `subfigure`.

[image]

This is achieved with this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[left=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,shapes,positioning,petri,topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering

                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_1$}
                \label{fig:20140812k1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}

                \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_2$}
                \label{fig:20140806k2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (1,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (3,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (2,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_3$}
                \label{fig:20140812k3}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (1,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (5,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (3,2) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (3,4) [circle, draw] {};
                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_4$}
                \label{fig:20140812k4}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (4,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (1,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (5,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v5) at (3,4) [circle, draw] {};

                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_5$}
                \label{fig:20140812k5}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
                    \node (v1) at (2,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v2) at (4,1) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v3) at (1,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v4) at (5,3) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v5) at (2,5) [circle, draw] {};
                    \node (v6) at (4,5) [circle, draw] {};

                    \draw (v1) -- (v2);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v1) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v3);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v2) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v4);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v3) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v5);
                    \draw (v4) -- (v6);
                    \draw (v5) -- (v6);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{$K_6$}
                \label{fig:20140812k6}
        \end{subfigure}%
         \caption{Vollständige Graphen $K_1$ bi $K_6$}\label{fig:completeGraphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment—at least until we receive further clarification from the OP—as it doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: As far as I've understood what the OP wants, my answer DOES give him the hints needed to achieve his goal. Both vertical and horizontal alignments are done, as well as the six elements in the same line. And I'm also giving an alternative for the case when the margins won't be enough to hold the six elements in the same line.

Comment: The MWE makes this more appropriate as an answer, I think. Why not use `.16\textwidth` for all `subfigure`s, though? There are 6, which means they will all fit on the page then. With `scale=0.50`, there will be some overlap between the fifth and sixth `subfigure`s, but then the `scale` could just be made to be smaller across the board. The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to adjust the margins, and it will work with any margins.

Comment: Also a simple blank line (or a `\par`) would seem to be a better way to induce a new line if you want to split the `subfigure`s into two rows, rather than using `\\ `.

Comment: I've been using `.16\textwidth` since the beginning. That's the reason of the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry; I misread that paragraph. Nonetheless, why not just change the `scale` factor, rather than having to worry about margins?

Comment: HI, It would be possible to top align each `tikzpicture`?