# Align independent tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have two `tikzpictures`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{notarget} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum
  width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=none,
  opacity=0,text opacity=1,align=center]
\tikzstyle{target} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum
  height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, very thick,text
  opacity=1,align=center]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, right of=n3] {girl\\NN};
%      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- ++(1cm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad\qquad
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, below of=n3,anchor=north] {girl\\NN};
      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:rightaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I do not know how to align the to figures vertically, currently it shows like this:

[image]

I would like to align it like this:

[image]

I have tried the following answers, without success:

- [cannot figure out how to produce some tikz pictures next to each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196051/cannot-figure-out-how-to-produce-some-tikz-pictures-next-to-each-other)
- [Inline TikZ - vertical centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57019/inline-tikz-vertical-centering)
- [How to make a tikz node, top-aligned with the rest of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39597/how-to-make-a-tikz-node-top-aligned-with-the-rest-of-the-text)

**UPDATE**

I get it working with the help of Guilherme, here is:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right=of n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right=of n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, right=of n3] {girl\\NN};
      \node (n4') [target, right=of n4,draw=none,anchor=west] {};
      \node (n5') [target, below=5mm of n4',anchor=north,draw=none] {};
      \draw [thick,->] (n5'.center) -- ++(5mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad\qquad
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right=of n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (nn) [notarget,draw=none,right=of n2] {};
      \node (n3) [target, right=of nn] {girl\\NN};
      \node (n4) [target, below=5mm of n3] {a\\DT};
      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

And the result:
[image: finish]

**UPDATE 2**

Finally I've used gemot's solution:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}cp{0.4\textwidth}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm,baseline=(n3)]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right=of n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right=of n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, right=of n3] {girl\\NN};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \tikz\draw [thick,->] (0,0) -- ++(.5cm,0);
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm,baseline=(n3)]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right=of n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right=of n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, below=5mm of n3,anchor=north] {girl\\NN};
      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
    \subcaption{}
  &&
    \subcaption{}
  \end{tabular}
  \label{fig:rightaction}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: One way would be to use `\tikzmark`(many examples on this site) to mark an alignment point in the first picture and use that in the second picture to do the alignment. This will require two consiecutive runs of `pdflatex`.

Comment: I am trying yo use `tikzmark` now, thanks,

Comment: If you can't get it to work fully post how far you got and am sure someone here will help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not require phantom drawings.

- Use the `baseline` option of `tikzpicture` to specify the horizonal alignment.
- Use some `tabular` environment for the overall arrangement. Because of the captions, you have to use `p` columns or some other type creating a box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzset
  {common/.style =
    {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
     text centered, text opacity=1, align=center
    }
  ,notarget/.style = {common, draw=none, opacity=0}
  ,target/.style   = {common, draw=black, very thick}
  }

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}cp{0.4\textwidth}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm,baseline=(n3)]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, right of=n3] {girl\\NN};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  &
    \tikz\draw [thick,->] (0,0) -- ++(1cm,0);
  &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm,baseline=(n3)]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, below of=n3,anchor=north] {girl\\NN};
      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
    \subcaption{before}
  &&
    \subcaption{after}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A transformation}\label{fig:rightaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am going to keep with this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are probably lots of ways to do this. Two I can see easily implemented: (i) use a `\savebox` and `\raisebox` or (ii) do the same drawing, but invisible (with `\path`). I'll show only the second because I think it's considerably less complicated and, as far as I know, the `\savebox`/`\raisebox` solution is already in the site.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzset{notarget/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum
  width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=none,
  opacity=0,text opacity=1,align=center},
    target/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum
  height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, very thick,text
  opacity=1,align=center}}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, right of=n3] {girl\\NN};
      \node (n4') [target, below of=n3,anchor=north,draw=none] {};% <<<<<<< INVISIBLE
      \path [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);% <<<<<<<<<<< INVISIBLE
%      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- ++(1cm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \qquad\qquad
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]
      \node (n1) [notarget] {I\\PRP};
      \node (n2) [notarget, right of=n1] {saw\\VBD};
      \node (n3) [target, right of=n2] {a\\DT};
      \node (n4) [target, below of=n3,anchor=north] {girl\\NN};
      \draw [thick,->] (n4) -- (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:rightaction}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```